# Babi Guling - Balinese Suckling Pig - alternative cuts of pork for it?

Tags: substitutions, pork

I love **Babi Guling - Balinese Suckling Pig** which I've made twice so far.  As I am mostly cooking for 3, I obviously can't use a whole suckling pig.

Here's a typical recipe:  [adventurefoodie.blogspot.ca/2011/08/babi-guling-balinese-pig](http://adventurefoodie.blogspot.ca/2011/08/babi-guling-balinese-pig.html?m=1)

What I have used so far is pork belly cuts.  Sandwich the Babi Guling filling between two slabs and off to the oven.  They taste great, but just a bit too rich and fatty for my own taste and diet.  At the same time, I am worried that a less fatty cut would end up dry from the cooking.  Or, maybe rather than a total replacement, I would keep the top half as pork belly and the another cut on the bottom?

Comment: First thought would be the neck or shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

The pork fat is what gives the taste, so if you would take a less fatty cut of pork, just use a trusted method of preventing it from drying out and that is larding:

- add most of the pork Babi Gulling filling inside the cut
- smear some pork Babi Gulling filling *around* the cut
- cover the cut with pork belly strips (=bacon) as well
- use tooth picks to prevent the pork belly strips to fall off.

Comment: P.S. You're probably going to use Pancetta instead of bacon, but that's better! (if I get your nationality correctly: [edit your profile](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/64096/italian-philosopher) to provide more information about yourself...)